# Change value from 0 to something on tooltip only

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chartjs with Bootstrap 4, on version 2.6.0.

Everything is working fine, except that I'm trying to replace an information when value is 0 on tooltip to not voted yet
I've tried a lot, and can't figure it out.

[Graph picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmGv1.png)

Can you help me?
There's an image attached that illustrates.

The value should still be zero inside the Graph, but I need to translate this information on the tooltip when the value is 0.

My code already has this information:

```
tooltips: {
            custom: function(tooltip) {
                if (!tooltip) return;
                // disable displaying the color box;
                tooltip.displayColors = false;  
              },
            callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return this._data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
                }
            }
        },
```

Thanks a lot.

Edit: [Here is the second image after the suggested fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kGQR.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good with it but this will get it done. You might have to work it differently. But if you put how you are creating your chart then I can make it an exact match. Essentially you will want this:

```
callbacks: {
    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return this._data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
    },

    label: function(tooltipItem, data){
        var lab = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        return lab === 0 ? "Não Avaliado" : "Avaliação Geral: " + lab;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it is partially fixed. When result is 0, it is now OK. But when the result is not 0, the information "Avaliação Geral: " before the value is missing. It is only showing the value number on the second line.
Can you help with that? I've posted another image to illustrate.

Comment: You're a genius! It worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndréLuizPaiz No prob. Please accept my answer if it's completely done what you needed.